# Get nested settings in Sinatra dynamically

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In Sinatra (using Sinatra::Configfile) getting a simple setting is very easy with something like `settings.foo`, but if you need to put your settings in a hierarchy, it's not entirely obvious how to do it in a simple and direct way.

This is painfully verbose:

```
get '/test' do
  case settings.environment
  when :production
    settings.production['foo'] 
  else
    settings.development['foo'] 
  end
end
```

Something closer to this would be much better, but this doesn't work:

```
get '/test' do
  settings[settings.environment]['foo'] 
end
```

Comment: How about `settings.send(settings.environment)['foo']`?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of doing something like that, but I'm assuming there's a more standard (and simple/elegant/readable) Sinatra way of doing this...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `send` to call a method on an object using a string.

```
get '/test' do
  settings.send(settings.environment.to_s)['foo'] 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [`configure`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Configuration)?

```
set :foo, "default value\n" # or explicitly set for each environment 
                            # with different configure blocks

configure :production do
  set :foo, "production\n"
end

get '/test' do
  settings.foo
end
```

Comment: No: I want these configurations in a YAML file.

Comment: @iconoclast are you using [Sinatra::ConfigFile](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/config_file.html) or something similar? `settings` by itself doesn’t use Yaml.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are going for.

At the top of your Sinatra app add the following.

```
require 'sinatra/config_file'
config_file './config/config.yml' # Point to wherever you want to store your config.yml

# Within your config.yml specify per environment settings; very similar to Rails
development:
  database: sqlite://../bigtunadev.db
  cipher: lamecipher4dev
  oracle: 
    user: oracle_user 
    password: oracle_password
  db2:
    user: db2_user
    password: db2_password
  mysql:
    user: mysql_user
    password: mysql_password

production:
  database: sqlite://../bigtunaprod.db
  cipher: wA7Th1515@n@w3s0m3c1p43r
```

By default only `test, production, and development` environments are supported.

If you would like to add additional environments then you will have to override it in your configure like follows.

```
set :environments, %w{development test production staging}
```

This will expose the properties directly on settings for your current environment.

---

Notice under the development section where I've added additional nesting.

The multi level nests must be accessed as a hash so it will look something like follows.

`settings.oracle["user"]`

Comment: Yes, that's good to know for the example I gave, but I'd like a generalized way of getting hierarchical info.  For instance, imagine a Sinatra-based API that pulls data from different RDBMSs.  I might have need oracle.user and oracle.password on one request, but db2.user and db2.password on another.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you should be able to follow the original example I gave and just extend the YAML nesting.  The only oddity is that beyond the first nested level it must be accessed as a hash rather than using dot notation.  I've added some additional information to my sample above to hopefully clarify.  If that is still not what you are looking for maybe we can follow up in a private chat room so the thread doesn't carry on too long.

Comment: I don't want to do `settings.oracle["user"]` because the code needs to be dynamic.  I need something like `settings["database"]["user"]`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to do something like this? `settings[#{database}]["user"]`